# showint that a sequence lives in an open ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

LEt $B(a,r) = \{ x : ||x-a|| < r \} $, $E = \partial B(a,r) = \{ x : ||x-a|| = r \}$

Let $y \in E$, so $||y-a|| = r$. I want to show that the sequence

$$ y_n = a + r\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)(y-a) $$

converges to $y$ and that $y_n \in B(a,r)$.

#### My try

$$ ||y_n - a|| = ||r\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)(y-a)|| = || r^2 \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)||$$

How can I show that this quantity is $< r$ ?

Also, to show $y_n \to y$,

$$ ||y_n - y|| = || a - y + r\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)(y-a)|| \leq ||a-y|| + ||r\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)(y-a)||$$

But, i dont know how to show this last quantity goes to $0$

Any help would be appreaciated. thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should try $ y_n = a + \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)(y-a) $ instead.

Comment: $$r^2\left(1-\frac1n\right)<r\iff r\left(1-\frac1n\right)<1\;\ldots$$ Did you forget to add the condition $\;r<1\;$ ?

Comment: It doesnt let me edit my comment or even delete it. my apology but basically i stated what you have down here.

Comment: Yes @BigM , we only have 5 minutes after the we post the comment  to edit it. After that it all is lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BigM's idea:

$$\left\|y_n-a\right\|=\left\|\left(1-\frac1n\right)(y-a)\right\|=\left|1-\frac1n\right|\left\|y-a\right\|<\left\|y-a\right\|=r$$

And about convergence:

$$\left\|y_n-y\right\|=\left\|y\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)-1\right)-a\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)-1\right)\right\|=\frac1n\left\|y-a\right\|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$